# binary search in typescript vs indexOf - how to get performance properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, search

I wrote wrote binary search algorithm with some typescript and i wanted to get its performance against array.indexOf. My result show that typescript version is slower. I tried to measure performance in available benchmarks on web and they show that binary search is much faster (as it should be). Whats wrong with this code / typescript / the way im trying to get performance of functions?

I tried benchmarks and results look completely different. http://jsben.ch/VBjt0

My code below.

```
function binarySearch(
  sortedArray: number[],
  seekElement: number,
): number {
  let startIndex = 0;
  let endIndex: number = sortedArray.length - 1;
  while (startIndex <= endIndex) {
    const mid = startIndex + Math.floor((endIndex - startIndex) / 2);
    const guess = sortedArray[mid];
    if (guess === seekElement) {
      return mid;
    } else if (guess > seekElement) {
      endIndex = mid - 1;
    } else {
      startIndex = mid + 1;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

const indexOfSearch = function(arr, element) {
  return arr.indexOf(element);
};

const testArray = [...Array(100000).keys()].map(x => x + 1);


console.time('binarySearch');
binarySearch(testArray, 4400) // binarySearch: 0.134ms
console.timeEnd('binarySearch');

console.time('indexOfSearch');
indexOfSearch(testArray, 4400) // indexOfSearch: 0.029ms
console.timeEnd('indexOfSearch');
```

I also tried to use `performance.now` with this util function:

```
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks';

export const getPerformance = (func: Function, ...params) => {
  const start = performance.now();

  func(params);

  const end = performance.now();

  console.log(`${func.name} took ${end - start} milliseconds to execute`);
}
```

but results are even worse. With the same testing array binary search using `getPerformance` function took 11ms while indexOf took 0.003ms. Its weird and i don't know what im doing wrong. Thanks for any help

Comment: You might try replacing the `Math.floor()` call with `((endIndex - startIndex) / 2) | 0` or maybe `(endIndex - startIndex) >> 1`

Comment: Also the JavaScript runtime (well, most modern runtimes) will eventually compile your search function, so it would be good to try the performance test many times.

Comment: Results with your suggestion:
binarySearch: 0.134ms
indexOfSearch: 0.029ms
Still indexOf is faster :/

Comment: I share your puzzlement at how fast `.indexOf()` seems to be. I personally find it amazing.

Comment: Why are you picking `4400` as your target? This is close to the beginning of the array of `100000` elements, so it's possible that the function calls to `Math.floor` and other overhead of your binary search is always dwarfed by the optimized linear search. Pick a random number in the array. Even so, when I run your benchmark, binary search is faster as expected. If I use the worst case scenario I get `indexOf` => 979 ms and `binarySearch` => 32 ms.

Comment: Great idea. I changed it to `99999` and i this is my result with console.time 
binarySearch: 0.133ms
indexOfSearch: 0.147ms

Comment: 0.133ms vs 0.147ms is still not a big difference. A linear scan is only about 10% slower than a binary search, in that case. I guess the `indexOf` has a very optimised native implementation. You can try running the test a lot to perform a warm-up first, as Pointy mentioned.

Comment: The supplied `indexof()` function is a black-box:  it works but you don't know how.  Also, since a binary search requires that the table be sorted, while `indexof()` does not, in order to "properly" compare the two you'd need to consider the resources needed to sort the array *(once ...)*.

Answer (score 2):

For an array of length , the binary search should need to check ₂ entries at the worst case, while the linear scan would take  entries at the worst case.  For  = 100,000 as in your example, that means in the worst case you'd expect to be checking 100,000 / ₂ 100,000 ≈ 6,000 as many entries in your linear scan as you would in your binary search.  Obviously the implementation details can change things by some numeric factor, but I'd be very surprised if you don't see some large difference between the two.

As the comments mention, you should really be doing the search many many times before you can get a sense of the average performance.  A single run of any small bit of code is likely to have a bunch of overhead that can dwarf any differences.  Here's one possible way to do this:

```
const N = 10000;
const seekElements = [...Array(N)].map(k => Math.floor(Math.random() * len * 1.1));

console.time('binarySearch');
for (let el of seekElements) {
    binarySearch(testArray, el)
}
console.timeEnd('binarySearch'); // 6 ms / N = 0.6 microseconds per search

console.time('indexOfSearch');
for (let el of seekElements) {
    indexOfSearch(testArray, el)
}
console.timeEnd('indexOfSearch'); // 3215 ms / N = 320 microseconds per search
```

Here I've set up an array of 10,000 random elements to find, about 10% of which are not in the array.  The particular distribution of elements to seek will have an impact on the search time, since values not present in the array will be the worst-case performance in both search strategies.  By testing 10,000 searches instead of 1, we can divide the timer's result by 10,000 to get an average time per search.

Anyway, in the my tests on my browser, I see that the `indexOf()` search on average is taking 320 microseconds while the binary search is taking 0.5 microseconds.  There's at least a 500-fold improvement with the binary search.  It's not 6,000, but it's definitely an improvement.  You could try speeding up the implementation a bit by using `x>>1` instead of `Math.floor(x/2)`, but I'm not sure how important that is to you.

Okay, hope that helps.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-5vQqbFjSW6oADEDG408E7Wszn86R5F5idNZvNFphSBPiMlOC44AJM4gAFS+jTrgrJcsVkXV7pwVTJWDqUgAclQGBw6swJAv++ADEq1jNiDgPzboPJmlo1uoa8sDwQh7zIcMoHjU0MQMGVm3oE8z3wRQXEvIDb1Ah9jj2fYADZelufZ628HxknwvoIEwOAsXlZhbjzERgQ1KtQ2PfBTxgc8LydNxVTvLCTmfMxE2Cd9PxJH9wU7ACeL4zDwOuSC+2g5RYMoYVWMQzjkNQ7jtjkjVHwCXZ9gAZgOfIAFYCL2RBiMQcyfF6GBKOo-BaPoxisWYg8gA)

Comment: Thanks for the great insight!

Answer (score -3):

```
indexOf()
```

is written in binary, it is call, to "hard coded" function, which has soft interface of JavaScript.

```
probably it's also binary search
```

developers of JavaScript aren't stupid. The way you're accessing variables, trough OP codes and tokens and all virtual sandbox, you never reach the speed of light(C).

If you benchmark good in plain JavaScript, you should implement in real program of browser or node, not just sandbox.

JavaScript been about performance, when avg. laptops haven't shipped with 8GB ram. It's more about the simplicity of doing things, that computer gets done. Computers are cheaper than human nowadays.

If you want to benchmark really good, write it in WebAssembly or compile to it with C. Or write Node.js extensions. But while spending time, consider the following: ability to do a task, is far much more than few miliseconds.

Comment: This answer is incoherent. `indexOf` [is in no way a binary search](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/0445fa297127d1b22cbfc39bc48a0b7b4e42031e/src/runtime/runtime-array.cc#L318).

Comment: How can it be done with binary search if there's no guarantee the array is sorted?